# Apply fade transition to slideshow in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know this topic has already been discussed, but I can't understand how to apply the suggestions to my work. I have this code:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 7000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="capa1.png" class="slideshow">
  <img src="capa2.png" class="slideshow">
  <img src="capa3.png" class="slideshow">
  <img src="capa4.png" class="slideshow">
  <img src="capa5.png" class="slideshow">
  <img src="capa6.png" class="slideshow">
</div>
```

How can I apply a fade-in transition to the images on the `header` div?

Comment: *"this topic has already been discussed"*, please add what didn't work in those topic discussions.  Right now, we don't know what you have tried and what did or did not work.  We don't want to suggest things that you have already tried.

Comment: @zero298 the thing is I can't replicate what has been suggested in the other topics. I think I am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example but I had to adjust a few things so take a close look at this example.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();
setInterval(carousel, 3000);

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.querySelectorAll('#header img');
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
#header {
  height: 255px;
  position: relative;
}

#header img {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  position: absolute;
  height: 255px;
}

#header img.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162971/potatoes-french-mourning-funny-162971.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="active">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/209620/pexels-photo-209620.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/321552/pexels-photo-321552.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
</div>
<p>
  asd asd asd asd
</p>
</p>
```

Pay close attention to the css styles, specifically the use of absolute and relative positioning as well as the css transitions. Also i converted it to use setInteval instead of a recursive setTimeout.